# Assigning a variable with a select from - plsql

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to do some like this:

Declare  VariableName varchar2(50)

Begin VariableName := (select column from table where rownum = 1);

What's the problem?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `select into`.

Like this:

```
select column into VariableName from table where rownum = 1;
```

If you have more than one variable, you can achieve that by separating them with a `,`:

```
declare
    a number;
    b date;
    c varchar2(100);
begin
    select ca, sysdate, cc
      into a, b, c
      from your_table
     where rownum = 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

put a semicolon after declare statement
Declare VariableName varchar2(50);

Answer (score 0):

You can better use a `SELECT INTO` for this, or even better a cursor with a record. A `SELECT INTO` will work, but if the SELECT statement doesn't return any record you will get a `ORA-01403: no data found` error. Wich are annoying to find if you have more code.

For example:

```
DECLARE
        CURSOR cTable IS
               SELECT ColumnA FROM Table WHERE RowNum = 1;
        rTable cTable%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
        OPEN cTable;
        FETCH cTable INTO rTable;
        CLOSE cTable;
        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rTable.ColumnA);
END;
/
```